# Choosing between SQL Server Express and SQL Lite

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I have a project requirement to choose a light database for the application.

It's required to choose between SQL Server Express Edition or SQLLite. Which one would be efficient and reliable. I am supposed to run it under Windows 7/Windows 2008 R2. I am newbie in the database programming. It would be helpful if you can share some information in terms of

1. Reliability
2. Stability
3. Size Limits
4. Memory consumption
5. Performance

Comment: Do you mean SQL Server Compact Edition?

Comment: No SQL Server 2008 Express Edition. Is it possible to download compact edition?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

SQL Server Express and SQLite aren't really comparable database systems.

- **SQL Server Express** is the free version of Microsofts full SQL Server product, a standalone database server (often run on a dedicated machine) that client applications connect to.  It is designed for things like web applications where many users will be using the database at the same time and there is a requirement for high availability.
- **SQLite** is a compact in-process database that is often used in applications that benefit from having access to a SQL based database system however it isn't feasible to install a full standalone database alongside the application.  For example Firefox uses SQLite to store bookmarks and Adobe Lightroom uses it to store its photos catalog, there are also several mobile (e.g. iPhone) applications that use SQLite.

The Microsoft equivalent to SQLite would be [SQL Server compact edition (CE)](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) which is free to distribute and use.  SQL Server CE is very similar to SQLite in most respects.

Similarly the non-Micrososft equivalent of SQL Server (both the Express edition and the full edition) would probably be [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).

Although there are crossovers (you might build a small web application that uses SQLite, or a large desktop application that requires users to install SQL Express) typically the choice between the two "types" of database system (in-process vs standalone database server) is down to the type of application being developed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be helpful if you can give inputs on memory overhead and stability issues (especially with in-proc DBs). I have one more specific question, comparing to the system overhead created by SQL Server; can we benefit any less system load (specifically in terms of memory and performance) up on using SQL Server Express Edition?

Comment: @sarat The only benefit of using the Express edition over the full edition is cost.  I'm not sure what I can really offer with regards to memory use / stability, you will probably be better off posting another question with your specific concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You might find more details in the following article: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2011/01/comparison-of-sql-server-compact-4-and.html

Comment: Can you enhance your answer some? Questions that are basically just links aren't very helpful if the blog vanishes. Further, the accepted answer made a much better effort (3.5 years ago) to answer the question.